# Recyclerview not displaying list item but gray background and text "android...RecyclerView"

Tags: api, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview, kotlin-android-extensions

i am a new to Kotlin Android development,i added recycler view to my project and then move the icon to the layout according to the tutorial i was watching but it not displaying anything except gray background and this black text "andriod...recycler"  instead of displaying the list items samples as in the tutorial

i suspect it the api level, the android studio version is 3.1
it on Api28, here is the activity_hobbies.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

this is HobbiesActivity.tk

```
package org.blessedmedia.www.kotlinapp

import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity

class HobbiesActivity : AppCompatActivity(){
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hobbies)
      }

  }
```

if you need any more file to provide solution.kindly comment

Comment: just go to Build -> Clear Project.

Comment: @ArsalanKhan have done that still  it didnt work

Comment: clear project and rebuild project. If view still shows "andriod...recycler" this then ignore it. Its just for view nothing else. When you run your app it will gone

Comment: ohh i noticed as much after building the project as a signed  apk  it displayed  when installed but blank ...i will proceed with the tutorial..but what do you think might be the cause?

Comment: sometime xml not load views and that's why this happen to you.

Comment: Could you please add code for RecyclerView Adapter and ViewHolder as well?

Comment: recyclerview Adapter and Viewholder code not in place as at then ,m just learning

Comment: @BlessedMedia If you are just working with layouts, you don't actually need `ViewHolder` or `Adapter` to preview how your `RecyclerView` will look like: Please add these lines in the `<RecyclerView ../>` tag in xml. 
`tools:listitem="@layout/your_list_item_view.xml
 tools:itemCount="10"
 tools:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"`